# Web Credentials showing Error 0x80070057 "The parameter is incorrect"

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge, credentials-manager

I am running windows 10, it has been working fine for a while.

Recently I got a notification in the `Action Center`. It said:

```
Click here to enter you most recent credential 
Your Microsoft account needs you to sign in again
```

Clicking the notification eventually lead me to the `Credential Manager`. But when I click the `Web Credentials` tab, I get the following error

[image: Credential Manager: Error An error occurred while performing this action. Error code: 0x80070057 Error Message: The parameter is incorrect.]

No web credentials are shown. Nothing is listed below the `Web Credentials` heading.

I don't know why. I'd like to fix it. I'm pretty sure that the `Web Credentials` has worked before.

I have tried these remedies with no improvement:

- Restarting the computer
- Modifying the Credential Manager startup type. It was on Manual, but setting it to Automatic did nothing (In both cases, it was already running)
- Setting Edge to the default browser (was Chrome)
- Erased all managed passwords in Edge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix the problem by removing the contents of this folder

```
C:\Documents and Settings\<USERNAME>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Protect
```

Doing so will **erase all login credentials** for all apps for your user account! That is all usernames and passwords, including those inside Google Chrome.

But after having done that, the `Web Credentials` tab seems to work again.

Thanks to Kapil Arya who added this solution to [his post](http://www.kapilarya.com/fix-windows-10-credential-manager-error-0x80070057).

Answer (score 0):

There is another possible solution.

**Solution 1**: Add a registry key value

1. Click Start button and type `Regedit.exe` in the search box and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.
2. Now you can see the Registry Editor. Try to find out the registry subkey following the path below and click it:
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\SystemCertificates`
3. Click the `Edit` menu and move mouse to New and then click `DWORD Value`. Next right-click `CopyFileBufferedSynchronousIo` and click `Modify`.
4. Type `1` and click `OK` on the `Value` data box. Exit Registry Editor and restart your PC.

There are other possible solutions on this page: http://www.eassos.com/how-to/fix-error-code-0x80070057.php